# Using usort to sort Arrays of Arrays with Arrays PHP

Tags: php, sorting, php-5.2

I have an array of arrays with arrays in PHP and I want to sort the top level of the array based on a field within each element, and I also want to sort an array within each element based on an element of an array of that element. (see example). I want it so that in the end, `$data` has first the item with the `'primary'` value of 'first' then 'second'. I also want it so that within 'first' and 'second', the array under the field `'secondary'` has first the item with the `'val'` of 'foo' then 'bar' (for both 'first' and 'second')

```
$data = array (
    array (
        'myid'      => 4,
        'primary'   => 'second',
        'secondary' => array (
            array (
                'myid' => 10,
                'val'  => 'bar',
            ),
            array (
                'myid' => 8,
                'val'  => 'foo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    array (
        'myid'      => 2,
        'primary'   => 'first',
        'secondary' => array (
            array (
                'myid' => 10,
                'val'  => 'bar',
            ),
            array (
                'myid' => 8,
                'val'  => 'foo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

function mysort($a, $b) {
    return $a['myid'] > $b['myid'];
}

echo "pre sort:\n";
print_r($data);

usort($data, 'mysort');

echo "post top level sort:\n";
print_r($data);

foreach ($data as $k=>$item) {
    usort($item['secondary'], 'mysort');
    echo "Second Level Item sort:\n";
    print_r($item['secondary']);
}

echo "post second level sort:\n";
print_r($data);
```

Why am I getting the following final output?

```
post second level sort:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [myid] => 2
            [primary] => first
            [secondary] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [myid] => 10
                            [val] => bar
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [myid] => 8
                            [val] => foo
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [myid] => 4
            [primary] => second
            [secondary] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [myid] => 10
                            [val] => bar
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [myid] => 8
                            [val] => foo
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

By the way I'm using PHP 5.2.17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ($data as $k=>&$item) {
    usort($item['secondary'], 'mysort');
    echo "Second Level Item sort:\n";
    print_r($item['secondary']);
}
```

**Why this is so?**

Because by default `foreach` copy all vars in it.
So if you change variable in `foreach` you change only local variable, and after `foreach` is end, the variable will be se same as before `foreach`

When you add `&` - than `foreach` not copy variables, and using it by reference

Comment: Thanks! I figured that that was what was going on, but didn't know to use the `&`.